# Jquery mobile checkbox not checked when value is retrieved from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, cordova

In my phonegap application i use `jquery mobile`. When `retrieve the value from my DB` the other fields are filled correctly(`textbox values are filled correctly`) works `except checkbox`. My problem is when the `DB returns true or false` whatever it is there is `no changes in my checkbox`. I struggled this issue for two days anyone suggest the solution to solve this one..

My coding is like:

```
 if (results.rows.item(0).checkbox1 == true) 
     $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', 'checked');
 else $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked');
```

Tried this also:

```
//$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
 //$("input[id='checkbox1']").attr("checked",results.rows.item(0).checkbox1).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

**solved:**
like

```
if (results.rows.item(0).checkbox1 === 'true') 
     $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', 'checked');
 else $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce this issue in fiddle?

Comment: @Purus when put in fiddle the onload is not working in fiddle

Comment: @Purus look at this http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/DtY4V/

Comment: You should be putting that in deviceready event when using cordova. document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {}, false);

Comment: edited my answere below. plz try that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dbValue = (results.rows.item(0).checkbox1 === true);
$('#checkbox1').prop('checked', dbValue);
```

Note the === in the first line. If your DB return value is something like 1 or the string "true", check for it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a refresh once you set the values dynamically to the form elements in jQuery Mobile.

For your case the method it is :

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    var a= true;
    alert("hi");
    if(a == true) {
       $("#checkbox1").attr("checked",true);
       $("#checkbox2").attr("checked",true);
    } else {
      $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked');
      $("#checkbox2").removeAttr('checked');
    }

    $("#checkbox1").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
}, false);
```

Comment: when i click the checkbox i need to click two times to uncheck it shows it is checked but not visible....

Comment: just have the above code and remove what you added in body tag onload.

Comment: What was the problem? was my answer of any use?